# Adding a line to an acces table from a vba userform

Tags: sql, vba, insert

I am relatively new to programming and have an issue I can't seem to overcome. I need to insert a record into an access table based on entries from a userform. I'm getting a syntax error on my sql query:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO appointment SET APPTID = '" & SETAPPTUF.apptid & _
 "', SET DOCTORID = '" & SETAPPTUF.drid & _
 "', SET PATIENTID ='" & SETAPPTUF.ptid & "'" & _
 "', SET APPTTIME ='" & SETAPPTUF.apptdate & "'"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add error message in your question.

Comment: `SET` is usually used in `UPDATE` statements. You need to research basic SQL `INSERT` instax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's is not the correct syntax for INSERT. Format is more like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (column1, column2) VALUES ('value 1','value 2')
```